# What Cordova.js to use

Tags: cordova

I've made a HTML/JS application with cordova 2.3.0. The version of cordova.js is the iOS version downloaded from the phonegap website.

When I build this application using https://build.phonegap.com/ it generates a file for each platform. The android version doesn't work ofcourse because the cordova.js file is for iOS.

I am probably missing something because I thought the point of phonegap was a platform-independent javascript code. So what Cordova.js should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With phonegap build, you shouldn't add any cordova.js in your project.
You should include phonegap.js (as if it was in the root of the project) in your html instead of cordova.js

And then phonegap build will add the cordova.js and phonegap.js files at the root of the project depending on the version (either automatically chosen or defined in config.xml).

I would also suggest you to move to phonegap 3 and use the CLI to build projects as it allows to have the same project structure for local and phonegap build projects, and you can even launch a build on phonegap build directly from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

**Cordova.js** helps to link b/w native code and html page. In detail, It gets the request from client, if some native function is called then it will be send to cordova.js. This will forward it to native code.